# linq query with join returning incorrect values/associations

Tags: c#, linq

I have a fantasy football website and on one page I let a user select up to 5 players to compare (for this example I used Peyton Manning, Aaron Rodgers, and Andrew Luck).  I run the following query to return all of the week-by-week stats for these players:

```
     var weekStats = from p in db.Players
                            join t in db.Teams on p.teamAbbre equals t.teamAbbre
                            join w in db.WeekStats on p.playerId equals w.playerId 
                            where (p.playerId == player0 || p.playerId == player1 || p.playerId == player2 || p.playerId == player3 || p.playerId == player4)
                                && w.season == 2014
                            select new PlayerIndexViewModel
                            {
                                player = p,
                                team = t,
                                weekStat = w

                            };
```

On first look, everything looks great and you get 16 results for each player.  But, I looked closer I saw it was only returning Peyton's stats for all three players!  (Now, most players wouldn't complain about getting Peyton's stats, but that isn't the point I suppose...)

I double/triple check and everything is correct in the db.  The following sql runs perfectly:

```
    select p.*, t.*, w.* from Player p
    join Team t on t.teamAbbre = p.teamAbbre
    join WeekStat w on w.playerId = p.playerId
    where
    w.season = 2014
    and (p.playerId = 2501863 or p.playerId = 2506363 or p.playerId = 2533031 or p.playerId = -1 or p.playerId = -1)
```

Note: In this example we only chose 3 players so the -1 are just dummies.

After doing some searching I read about "navigation" as an alternative to joins and tried the following but got the same results:

```
var weekStats2 = from w in db.WeekStats
                        where (w.playerId == player0 || w.playerId == player1 || w.playerId == player2 || w.playerId == player3 || w.playerId == player4)
                            && w.season == 2014
                        select new PlayerIndexViewModel
                        {
                            player = w.player,
                            team = w.player.Team,
                            weekStat = w

                        };
```

I also added a line where I look at one stat specifically to see what is going on:

```
    var weekStats2 = from w in db.WeekStats
                            where (w.playerId == player0 || w.playerId == player1 || w.playerId == player2 || w.playerId == player3 || w.playerId == player4)
                                && w.season == 2014
                            select new PlayerIndexViewModel
                            {
                                player = w.player,
                                team = w.player.Team,
                                weekStat = w,
                                statCat_5 = w.statCat_5

                            };
```

When I run that and step through the debugger, I see that the statCat_5 is correct for each player but the values inside weekStat all still duplicate Peyton's stats.  It's also strange that the correct week for Rodgers and Luck is missing (meaning that each of the 3 players had a different bye week so the associated week is missing from data).

I suppose my question is this:  Am I crazy?  What is wrong with my LINQ that is causing this weirdness?

-----------Edit
Here is the sql being run according to the debugger:

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[season] AS [season], 
[Extent2].[playerId] AS [playerId], 
[Extent2].[playerName] AS [playerName], 
[Extent2].[teamAbbre] AS [teamAbbre], 
[Extent2].[position] AS [position], 
[Extent3].[teamAbbre] AS [teamAbbre1], 
[Extent3].[geoName] AS [geoName], 
[Extent3].[teamName] AS [teamName], 
[Extent3].[conference] AS [conference], 
[Extent3].[division] AS [division], 
[Extent3].[imageURL] AS [imageURL], 
[Extent1].[weekNum] AS [weekNum], 
[Extent1].[playerId] AS [playerId1], 
[Extent1].[statCat_1] AS [statCat_1], 
[Extent1].[statCat_2] AS [statCat_2], 
[Extent1].[statCat_3] AS [statCat_3], 
[Extent1].[statCat_4] AS [statCat_4], 
[Extent1].[statCat_5] AS [statCat_5], 
.....
[Extent1].[statCat_90] AS [statCat_90], 
[Extent1].[statCat_91] AS [statCat_91]
FROM   [dbo].[WeekStat] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Player] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[playerId] = [Extent2].   [playerId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Team] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[teamAbbre] = [Extent3].[teamAbbre]
WHERE (2014 = [Extent1].[season]) AND ([Extent1].[playerId] IN          (@p__linq__0,@p__linq__1,@p__linq__2,@p__linq__3,@p__linq__4))}
```

When I paste that into sql server, it runs correctly (the individual players are getting their own stats and not just copies of Peyton's stats).

Comment: Not an answer but it might be helpful to know how to view the SQL generated by a Linq to SQL query http://stackoverflow.com/a/4900379/397817

Comment: `Look closer`... at what?

Comment: In your example, is Manning represented by `player0`? If so, what happens if you switch `player0` to represent one of your other example players?

Comment: I pasted the sql from the debugger into the original post.  When i run it in sql server it runs correctly.

Comment: @SvenGrosen I tried it in a different order and it always returns Manning's stats.  I believe that this is because it is default order by playerId and Manning has the smallest integer value playerId.  I haven't tried it but I'm pretty sure that if I picked a different player with a smaller playerId, that player's stats would be the ones repeated.

Answer (score 0):

As the SQL returns the expected results while the C# code does not, it looks like the problem is not related to the JOIN itself.

It looks more like a "value vs. reference" issue. A new instance of PlayerIndexViewModel is created for each player, but these reference an instance of Weekstats, and judging by the results it could be the same instance on all rows.

To check whether this is the problem, try assigning to weekStat a clone of w instead of w itself (assuming WeekStats is cloneable).

I cannot tell why this problem could impact WeekStats more than Players or Teams (as of the first code snippet); the answer could be in the way the classes were bound to tables.

A question on a similar matter was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761911/does-linq-new-up-memory-when-creating-returns)

Comment: Is it possible that my composite key on WeekStat caused this?

public class WeekStat
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("playerId")]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public virtual Player player { get; set; }
        public int playerId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public int season { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 3)]
        public int weekNum { get; set; }
.....

Comment: I should note also that not all of the weekStat values are identical.  In other words, week1's stats are different from week2's stats.  It is just that all three player's stats are matching week for week (excepting when there is a bye week).  So if weekStat is not binding correctly and we are just passing the same reference each time, why aren't all of the entries having the same data?

Comment: My reasoning was based on snipped #4 in the original post. If my understanding is correct, as browsing progresses statCat_5 remains correct, while weekstat.statCat_5 is wrong. As the two values were necessarily equal at some point, this can only mean that the instance referenced by weekStat changes later on (and this, a clone can easily fix). However, I admit I don't understand yet the reason behind this change.

Comment: I think that I understand your reasoning.  I'm wondering though, since the first player's stats are the only ones saved, is it possible that the opposite is happening?  What I mean is that instead of it being overwritten each time (new data copied onto the same reference each time) but rather ONLY the first one is being copied?  Each of the other records is not being saved at all?